# iOS: Programmatically access parental control operations?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, camera

I was wondering if there is a way programmatically, to control parental access permissions from an application?

Such as: An application that can set a database-verified parental access code for the access to the camera application. This will then be set for a certain amount of time or until that code is entered again by the person who knows the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  You cannot access this from your application's code unless you are dealing with a jailbroken application.